# Getting continuous status update without line feed

Tags: java

I am developing using Java on NetBeans 7.4 and am trying to get a continuous status update, on the same line with the following code.

```
for (start=0; start<startLimit; ++start){
    System.out.print("Index="+start+" of "+startLimit+"\r");
    System.out.flush();
}
```

I have two problems.

- I get a line feed, which I do not want.
- The output is not continuously updated.  I am running in debug mode and usually only get an update in the console window, of the IDE, when I break.  It seems that the output is not getting flushed with each cycle.

Comment: Run it outside of your IDE then, see how it behaves there.

Comment: How are you determining that you are getting a line feed?  If you are copy/pasting from the IDE, it's possible that the textbox you are copying from is doing it, or maybe the app you are copying to (like if it's Notepad).  As far as flushing, I am not sure why you are even doing that.  You don't usually flush the System.out PrintWriter.

Comment: What operating system are you on? Check what `System.getProperty("line.separator")` returns.

Comment: Sorry.  I meant to say I was running the applications on Windows 7.

Comment: @peter.petrov.  You are right.  It works fine from the DOS console.

Comment: @OtagoHarbour Yes because most IDE's console does not interpret special control character (like `'\b'` or `'\r'`).

Answer (score 0):

\r (carriage return) causes a line feed (just like '\n') in Windows

Comment: I thought that the following was true: "*New line character combinations for different OSs: **Windows** is `\r\n`, **Linux** is `\n`, and **MacOS** is `\r`.*"

Comment: I thought this was true, but OP's code is working for me at the Windows Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck with a backspace character instead of a carriage return. If the IDE's console doesn't interpret a carriage return correctly, it *probably* won't interpret a backspace correctly, but it's something to try:

```
String status = "";
for (start=0; start<startLimit; ++start){
    for (int i = 0; i < status.length(); i++) System.out.print('\b');
    status = "Index=" + start + " of " + startLimit;
    System.out.print(status);
}
```